# Is it enough to use Provider one time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In `react-native` when we use `redux` module we use `createStore` from 'redux'. And My question: is it enough to use `<Provider/>` one time which makes the Redux store available to the rest of our app.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store'

import App from './App'

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
)
```

Or we must also add `<Provider/>` somewhere?

Comment: https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you create a store with `redux` with the reducers for example just like below:

```
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

Then you need to use `<Provider>` wrapper only once:

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
   <Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Later if you want to access any of the object from the store you need to use `mapStateToProps` in your components. If any modification is needed you need to create actions and dispatch them with `mapDispatchToProps`.

From the the [documentation](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#passing-the-store):

> The option we recommend is to use a special React Redux component called  to magically make the store available to all container components in the application without passing it explicitly. You only need to use it once when you render the root component.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you only need to use Provider once to wrap your whole application.

Answer (score 0):

The question looks interesting. You need to understand how the `store` is available to every component wrapped inside the `<Provider>`.

When you wrap any `React` component inside `<Provider store={store}>` every component will have access to something called `context`, through which it is possible to share the data even it's not an immediate child.

> Context provides a way to share values like these between components without having to explicitly pass a prop through every level of the tree. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

As it states that context can be used in any child component without explicitly passing a prop.

The `<Provider>` exactly works the same way. And when you use the redux the `<Provider>` sets the context. And you need to use the `connect()` from the `react-redux` it uses the context set by the `<Provider>` to pass properties to your component wrapped in `connect() HOC`.

Hence you need to use the `<Provider>` only once in your application.